# Airflow - Invalid JSON configuration, must be a dict

Tags: json, python-3.x, airflow

Airflow version: 2.1.1

I'm trying to trigger the dag using config and passing below json

```
{"load_type":"full"}
```

but it throws an error saying "Invalid JSON configuration, must be a dict"

I tried to format the json as well with 3spaces, 2 spaces etc

```
{
   "load_type":"full"
}
```

But it didn't work. Before this verison I was using 2.0.2 and I was able to send json while triggering the dag.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in 2.1.1 which was fixed by [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16648)
Upgrading to Airflow 2.1.2 should resolve this issue.

In case you can't upgrade triggering the DAG from [CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.1/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#trigger) should work in 2.1.1:

```
airflow dags trigger [-h] [-c CONF] [-e EXEC_DATE] [-r RUN_ID] [-S SUBDIR] dag_id
```

Comment: Thanks Elad. I upgraded the image to 2.1.2 and Issue was resolved